# Avoid hiding dropdown on clicking on inside elements [react-bootstrap]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I want to hide a drop-down bot by clicking on elements inside it. I'm finding ways to do this via JQuery. Is there any way to do this by using JavaScript only with react-bootstrap ?

I'm calling following functions on onBlur:

```
hideButtons(e){
    console.log("We here!", e.target.id)
    if(e && e.relatedTarget){
        e.relatedTarget.click();
    }
    this.setState({showAccountButtons: false},()=>{
        console.log(this.state.showAccountButtons)
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share the rest of the code, namely the html bit, we need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

React-bootstrap has a prop `onSelect` which takes a callback. So just do the stuff you need to do in the callback.

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/

With the available info in your question, it looks like doing below is sufficient.

```js
hideButtons(e){
    this.setState({showAccountButtons: false},()=>{
        console.log(this.state.showAccountButtons)
    });
}
```

```js
<Dropdown onSelect={hideButtons} .../>
```

leave a comment if it doesn't work and also update your question with more info and I will update the answer if required